# Printing an iframe in electron shows a save dialog instead of a print dialog

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, printing, electron

I have a sample app on the branch: https://github.com/EricG-Personal/electron_pdfkit_test/tree/feature/with_iframe

It is a very simple react based app that upon launch, dynamically creates a PDF and loads it into an iframe.

I have an iframe with contains PDF content. I try to print this iframe with:

```
iframeloaded()
{
    console.log( "iframe loaded - printing" );

    // window.frames[0].focus();
    // window.frames[0].print();

    var myWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow();

    myWindow.webContents.print();
}
```

However, a save dialog appears instead of the expected print dialog.

Is there a way I can get the print dialog to appear?

The PDF that is saved does contain the correct content.

I am using the latest version of electron on the latest version of OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying PDF is only supported in the latest versions of electron (>1.7 I think) and you need to enable plugins.

To do this for a BrowserWindow you need to set `plugins:true`:

```
const window = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        plugins: true
    }
})
```

I'm not sure if this will work in an iframe though so you could try using the [`<webview>`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag) tag and ensure you [enable plugins](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#plugins):

```
<webview src="https://www.github.com/" plugins></webview>
```